# How can we derive the projection formula in general?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

The derivation of the well-known projection formula $proj_\vec{b}(\vec{a})=\frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{\vec{b}\cdot \vec{b}}\vec{b}$ uses an argument based completely on geometry. We assume vectors are arrows in a normal cartesian space and use the law of cosines (among other things).

But now let's say that we have a vector space made up of all polynomials of order < N, and call our inner product $$[a(x),b(x)]=\int_{-1}^1ab\ \mathrm{d}x$$ where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are in polynomials in our vector space.

Okay, easy enough. But now things are getting complicated: the idea of a projection is a bit different. Now when we say $proj_{b(x)}a(x)$ we mean to say "write $a(x)$ as the linear combination of the two vectors $b(x)$ and "something else", and give back only the part with $b(x)$". Obviously this "something else" is a polynomial that is orthogonal to $b(x)$....

....except that this isn't obvious at all. How can we say that just because the inner product of $b(x)$ and "something else" is $0$ that they have no "common directionality"? Even worse, what does "directionality" even mean?

So this is my question: "How can we derive the projection formula without making references to geometry?"

Thank you very much

Comment: To project $a$ onto $b$, minimize $f(\alpha) = ||b-\alpha a||^2$.

Comment: Linear algebra.

Comment: @Chester How does that work? I'm not sure I understand. Thank you for answering, by the way

Comment: @Chester Wait, did you mean  to say "minimize $f(x)=||b - fa||^2$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore my comment, I wrote it backwards I think. It's basically the same idea as with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$: minimize the residual error. To project $a$ onto $b$ means put $a$ into the space spanned by $b$ such that the residual error is minimal (see the diagram below).

Since the projection is in the space spanned by $b$, it is some scalar multiple of $b$. The squared-residual error is $||a-\alpha b||^2$. To minimize set:

$$
f(\alpha) = ||a-\alpha b||^2
$$

$$
f'(\alpha) = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{\langle a,b \rangle}{||b||^2}
$$

Note that the residual vector $a-\alpha b$ is orthogonal to $b$.

[image: ]]

Comment: Hmm, something goes wrong when I try to derive it:
$$f'(\alpha) = 2||a-\alpha b||(\frac{d}{d\alpha}a-\frac{d}{d\alpha}\alpha b) = 0\\\
-2b\sqrt{<a-\alpha b, a - \alpha b>}=0$$
But $b$ is not zero, so we can now say
$$<a-\alpha b, a - \alpha b> = 0$$
By the properties of the inner product, $a-\alpha b = 0$ However, I seem to have shown that $a$ must be a multiple of $b$.... did I perhaps make a mistake with the derivative?

Comment: use $f(\alpha) = ||a-\alpha b||^2 = ||a||^2 - 2\alpha\langle a,b \rangle + \alpha^2 ||b||^2$, and then differentiate.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. But why is the first derivation wrong? I did tacitly assume the chain rule would hold....

Comment: $\frac{d}{d\alpha} ||a-\alpha b||^2 = 2||a-\alpha b|| \frac{d}{d\alpha}||a-\alpha b||$, and $\frac{d}{d\alpha}||a-\alpha b|| \neq \frac{d}{d\alpha}a - \frac{d}{d\alpha}b$.

Comment: Ahh got it. Thank you very much, you helped me understand this and explained clearly. Cheers

Comment: No problem. Btw, since you are working with polynomials on $[-1,1]$, you might be interested in the [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), which result from applying Gram-Schmidt to the monomial basis.